# Graph API search people by Phone Number

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to search people by using phone number. If you open Facebook and type mobile number on search bar you get user that's belong to it. But I want to do with Graph API. There is option for search but it's provide only username.

```
 search/type=user&q=username

 search/type=user&q=03001234567 // (#200) Application does not have the capability to make this API call
```

How can I search users by using Mobile numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I search users by using Mobile numbers.

You can’t.

The search functionality provided via the UI, and the API search are two different things.

---

I assume Facebook is deliberately not exposing all the functionality via API, because that would just be too powerful a tool for all sorts of data mining.